# Fade in/out in random time intervals

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have an ImageButton and I want to make it fade in randomly and fade out after some time.

How can I do this?

With a thread? with a service? with something else?

Sorry if it is a very novice question. Thank you

Comment: Just for the record: try using a search engine first ... very often; you will be surprised how many times other people asked similar things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fade in/out the `imageButton` in random interval of 1-5 seconds.

```
private boolean fadeIn = false;
private final Random rand = new Random();

...

final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      imageButton.animate().alpha(fadeIn ? 1.0f : 0.0f).setDuration(500).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              fadeIn = !fadeIn;
          }
      });
      handler.postDelayed(this, randInt(1000, 5000));
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);

...

public int randInt(int min, int max) {
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: thank you, Can I control the duration of the fade in and fade out?

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, via `setDuration(ms)`. Updated the answer.